# Eclipse Console Not Showing Logs

Tags: android, eclipse, console

This may not be a programming question. But any help will be appreciated.

When I launch my android application in emulator, I used to get some kind of log message on console. Like below:

```
[2014-09-01 18:56:44 - POSStore] ------------------------------
[2014-09-01 18:56:44 - POSStore] Android Launch!
[2014-09-01 18:56:44 - POSStore] adb is running normally.
[2014-09-01 18:56:44 - POSStore] Performing com.POS.Store.LoginActivity activity launch
[2014-09-01 18:56:45 - POSStore] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'SamsungGalaxyS' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2014-09-01 18:56:45 - POSStore] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'SamsungGalaxyS'
[2014-09-01 18:56:54 - POSStore] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-09-01 18:56:54 - POSStore] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-09-01 18:57:28 - POSStore] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-09-01 18:57:28 - POSStore] Uploading POSStore.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-09-01 18:57:28 - POSStore] Installing POSStore.apk...
[2014-09-01 18:57:43 - POSStore] Success!
[2014-09-01 18:57:43 - POSStore] Starting activity com.POS.Store.LoginActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-09-01 18:57:44 - POSStore] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.POS.Store/.LoginActivity }
[2014-09-01 18:57:45 - POSStore] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.POS.Store' on port 8626
```

But suddenly console stopped showing logs. But application is launched successfully and running.

Why does console stopped showing application logs? I've updated my android version. Does this afects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Display Selected Console** drop down on top right side of your console window. And select **Android**.

[image: Console Image]

Comment: Stupid mistake. Thanks a ton.

Comment: +1  @MapleMable it only seems stupid now. It's all too easy to stare at something for HOURS and not see it. I had a ton of code not working due to SMS being represented in a folder called 'sms' with small letters. Took me absolutely hours to figure that out. NOW I feel stupid! :)